# SqlDataReader - This method or property cannot be called on Null values

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am using `SqlDataReader` to read the data

```
SqlDataReader reader;
connection.Open();
...
...
reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
     var address = new Adress()
      { 
        House = reader.GetString(1)
      }
```

Why is `reader.GetString(1)` throwing an error

> Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

Surprisingly data is available.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here..

Comment: What do you mean with _data is available_? The error message is pretty clear

Comment: I added a check to see data exists or not by using HasRows. ....
 if (reader.HasRows) is returning TRUE                
 but when I try to access the data it is throwing this error.

Comment: Just to ask, are you sure you're not wanting to get GetString(0)? GetString is zero-indexed and the first string in your return will be index 0 not a 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Call IsDBNull to check for null values before calling this method.

This means that the method doesn't protect your code from the presence of a null value in the row/field

```
 var address = new Adress()
 { 
    House = reader.IsDbNull(1) ? "" : reader.GetString(1),
    ....
 }
```

Of course this assumes that you want an empty string in case your field is null, if this is not the case then you could put whatever you like in the true part of the conditional operator or throw your own exception.

Comment: reader.HasRows is returning True here. then why this error msg ?

Comment: It seems that you have a misunderstanding about the workings of the datareader. Checking HasRows is correct but redundant. It tells you if there are Rows and in your context is useless because Read tells you the same thing. GetString takes a field from the current Row (the field at position 1) and if this field contains a DbNull.Value then you get the error for that line.

Comment: Personally I do `reader[1] as String` that gives you `null` if the database value was `DbNull.Value` or the string if it was a normal string.

Comment: Interesting, I am curious if this is better in terms of response time to get out the data.

Comment: Never been in a situation where the performance was marginal enough to test the difference.

Comment: One of the value is Null. Sorry I am not able to identify it quickly. Its my bad. Thank you all for quick suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the following to check if the value is null and handle it appropriately:

```
if (reader.IsDBNull(1))
```

or

```
if (reader["FieldName"] == DBNull.Value)
```